# NLog - Only log while debugging

Tags: nlog

Take this simple NLog example configuration:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

How can this be set up to only log while debugging, and not when run in production?

EDIT:

To make things a bit more challenging: My NLog configuration files are centralized, shared over all applications/services/sites. So I would like to avoid altering every single project and just modify the config files.

Comment: What is type of your application? In case of web app the best way is using [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The solution should be applicable to both web and desktop applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see three solutions here.

1) Using config file and its [transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx). For the moment the transformations are supported for web applications (Im talking about VS2012). For desktop app you need to install additional [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).

2) Use two targets, one for development (I assume debugging=development in your case) and the second for production. At runtime you need to leave actual one by [removing the other](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/M_NLog_Config_LoggingConfiguration_RemoveTarget.htm).

**UPDATE**

3) If you don't want to alter the projects it is possible to apply [custom conditions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Conditions) to the logger depending on custom Layout Renderer (see example of [how to make a custom layout renderer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/497730/NLogplusLayoutRendererplusforplusassemblyplusversi)). In your case the layout renderer should return current Build Configuration (Debug or Release) of executing assembly. As a result the condition will look like this:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="logfile">
        <filters>
            <when condition="equals('${buildConfiguration}','Release')" action="Ignore" />
        </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

where **${buildConfiguration}** is your custom layout renderer.

**PS** And dont forget to put this

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NameOfMyAssemblyThatContainsMyLayoutRenderer" />
</extensions>
```

to the nlog.config so NLog knows about the layout renderer.

Comment: Both solutions would work, but will require a lot of work and time (which I don't have). I would like to avoid altering every single project and just modify the config files (see edited question for details).

Comment: I've added new solution to my post.

Comment: Just tested this. Works like a charm!

Comment: how does the custom layout renderer look like for this particular expamle. I don't understand NLog docs on it. +1 if you can add that to your answer as well.

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution would be to have a `NLog.config` file (whose contents will be overriden - you'll see later), plus one NLog config file per solution configuration/environment (let's say, `NLog.debug.config` and `NLog.release.config`). For example:

[image: All needed NLog config files]

Then you configure a `Pre-build event command line` to copy the config file corresponding to the current active configuration:

[image: Pre-build event command line]

The complete command you should paste there:

```
del "$(ProjectDir)NLog.config"

if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Debug" (
  copy "$(ProjectDir)NLog.debug.config" "$(ProjectDir)NLog.config"
) else (
  copy "$(ProjectDir)NLog.release.config" "$(ProjectDir)NLog.config"
)
```

This will copy `NLog.debug.config` to `NLog.config` (effectively overriding it) if DEBUG is the current active configuration/environment, otherwise it will copy `NLog.release.config`.

A shorter version would look like this (note the file naming diference though):

```
del "$(ProjectDir)NLog.config"
copy "$(ProjectDir)NLog.$(ConfigurationName).config" "$(ProjectDir)NLog.config"
```

Another thing to note is that during compilation the compiler will throw various warnings about duplicate declarations related to NLog. The reason is that the compiler will find 2 (or more) distinct configuration files for NLog and their declarations will collide. In order to fix that you have to **change the `Properties` of each of your *extra* NLog configuration** files to make the build action not copy them. For example:

[image: NLog.debug.config Properties]

## Do not repeat yourself

Lastly, you may not want to duplicate common/shared targets|rules|whatnot to avoid having to change them in multiple files. To achieve that, you can move these common/shared parts to another file and use [<include />](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#include-files).

Comment: Our NLog.config is bound to source control so all our team members need to checkout the all NLog files in all projects? Or is there a way to make NLog use NLog.debug.config instead?

Comment: You don't need to version the `NLog.config`, only the config files for each environment (Debug, Release, etc). You may append `NLog.config` to the `.gitignore` if you wish.

Comment: The only proper solution for mis is the one here from jweyrich. However, there's something more you can do. Instead of a prebuild task for deleting and copying and messing with the original NLog.config, create NLog.Debug.config and NLog.Release.config and then add a Post-build event: copy "$(ProjectDir)NLog.$(ConfigurationName).config" "$(TargetDir)NLog.config" This will overwrite the NLog.config, but your source control will still be happy and intact, since the original NLog.config doesn't get overwritten, just in the output directory.

Comment: This solution become more complicated, when the project is multiplatform .NET Core targeting Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Davatar, the drawback of using Post-build event is it does not work when publishing the project. I would prefer your approach if the deployment is resolved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This answer [nLog forum](http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Changing-rules-depending-on-build-configuration-td5831407.html) worked for us.

Reprinted below incase it ever gets lost.

> What you can do is have two NLog.config files:
>
> NLog.config
>
> and NLog.Debug.config
>
> In your code, somewhere close to the main method you can do:
>
> #if DEBUG
>
> LogManager.Configuration = new
> XmlLoggingConfiguration("NLog.Debug.config");
>
> #endif
>
> Now if most of the configuration is the same you can perhaps use
> include files - put everything htat is common (targets, etc.) into
> NLog.common.config and reference it with
>
> NLog.debug.config:
>
> ```
> <include file="NLog.common.config" />
> ```
>
> ```
> <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="debug" />
> <logger name="*" minLevel="Info"  writeTo="viewer" final="true" />
> ```
>
> NLog.release.config:
>
> ```
> <include file="NLog.common.config" />
>
> <!-- Release  rules -->
> <logger name="*" minlevel="Info"  writeTo="file" />
> <logger name="*" minLevel="Error" writeTo="event" />
> ```
>
> Let me know if it helps.
>
> Jarek

Answer (score 3):

I have based my answer on @neleus answer above but it still took me hours to get something working. Here is the completed guide incl. how to set up the `LayoutRenderer`. For the `NLog.config` you need:

```xml
<extensions>
   <add assembly="AssemblyName" />
</extensions>

<target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" name="asyncProd">
  <target xsi:type="File" name="logfileProc" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${buildConfiguration}.log"/>
</target>

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="asyncProd">
  <filters>
    <when condition="equals('${buildConfiguration}','Debug')" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

The target above is only for newbees to NLog so they have something running more quickly. Using the custom LayoutRenderer in the filename helps with debugging as you can see it's output in the file that is produced.

Then create a class called `BuildConfigLayoutRenderer` which I adapted from neleus' [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/497730/NLogplusLayoutRendererplusforplusassemblyplusversi)

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("buildConfiguration")]
[ThreadAgnostic]
public class BuildConfigLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer {
    private String buildconfig;
    private String GetBuildConfig() {
        if (buildconfig != null) {
            return buildconfig;
        }

#if DEBUG
        buildconfig = "Debug";
#else
        buildconfig = "Release";
#endif
        return buildconfig;
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent) {
        builder.Append(GetBuildConfig());
    }
}
```

Important is the string passed into the `LayoutRendererAttribute`. They need to match with what you register (needs to happen as early as possible in your code; main()) and the `NLog.config`.

```cs
LayoutRenderer.Register<BuildConfigLayoutRenderer>("buildConfiguration");
```

Now `${buildConfiguration}` will work. 
You can also use this for even more build configurations but you need to remember to add the filter that ignores that rule. I also tried the opposite, meaning to have `action="Log"` in the rule to reduce the number of filters needed. Later I realised that is non-sense because the default is to use the logger... so you have to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If a little code is allowed at runtime then one can do this:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="myLogLevel" value="Off" />
    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="${var:myLogLevel}" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

And then at startup do this:

```
#if DEBUG
if (IsDebugMode)
{
    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myLogLevel"] = "Debug";
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
#endif
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules