# NLog adding separate rules for each staging environment

Tags: .net, nlog, error-logging

I want to configure NLog rules such that each of my staging environments will have separate rules. For example my local environment may have something like this: 
`

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="eventlog" />
  </rules>
```

`where as my QA environment will have something like this:`

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="database" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="eventlog" />
  </rules>
```

`How can one achieve this through config files?

Comment: Possibly related [NLog - Only log while debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33805780/298054).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Config Transformation File for each Stage. First you create a configuration in Visual Studio. The default configurations are "Debug" and "Release". You are free to add more like "QA" by klicking on the dropdown in the toolbar of VS and selecting "":

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Then you add a transformation file named "NLog.QA.config" to your project. You should check out [Slow Cheetah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/2.5.15) for getting more comfort on this.

The transformation file has a special synthax documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx). Check out the samples under the link.

When you build in with selected "QA"-configuration you will get a different NLog.config. If you have SlowCheetah installed propertly you can right-click the transform-file in Solution Explorer and you get "Preview Transform".